# An approach to missing values in time series: easy, universal (and wrong?)

Tags: time-series, missing-data, categorical-encoding, multiple-imputation, kalman-filter

Suppose I have time series data and am fitting some appropriate model to the dependent variable, with or without independent variables, but definitely with some temporal structure that I wish to estimate. Suppose, moreover, that some of the values for my dependent variable are missing.

Now, it seems to me that the simplest way of dealing with this is to insert zeros where the missing values are and then adjoin an n by m matrix of dummy variables to the data, where n is the number of missing values and m is the total number of values, missing or not, zero everywhere but with a single 1 in each column where the missing value is. It seems to me that this would fit all the missing values perfectly but still get the model coefficients right and rank the fit of competing models correctly.

However, virtually everyone seems to advocate much more complicated procedures, like multiple imputation or the Kalman filter, to deal with missing value problems. So I suspect that my suggestion suffers from some disastrous shortcoming. Is that true, and if so, what is it?

Comment: For the ease of discussion, let us assume that 1 time unit = 1 day... If I correctly understand your suggestion, it implies that on any missing day the model-implied residual is exactly 0. This may be unrealistic and screw up models with moving average and ARCH terms. That is if the fraction of missing days is substantial.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts, @stans - Reinstate Monica! Yes, the  model, including the dummies, would have a zero error on these days. But this is true regardless of the parameter values & residuals from the remaining days.  So maximization over the other parameters should ignore these values, since they are always the same. You would want to delete these days in calculating both total and explained variance.  However I think you are right if you applied this to days that should be missing, as when a market does not trade on weekends. There lag 1 of Mon. should be Fri. actual, not Sun. fitted